# Magento 2: Global variable doesn't work with RequireJS

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, global-variable

I'd create a HTML document with a script tag and add this URL

```
<script src ="https://assets.pagar.me/pagarme-js/3.0/pagarme.min.js"></script>
```

so, call the global variable **pagarme** in console browser.

I got this response:

```
{client: {…}, postback: {…}, company: {…}, validate: ƒ, search: ƒ, …}
```

**But in Magento 2, I always receive error messages.**

Below some files with my configuration:

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            pagarmeJs: 'https://assets.pagar.me/pagarme-js/3.0/pagarme.min.js'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        "pagarmeJs": {
            exports: "pagarme"
        }
    }
};
```

**jsFileWithTheCallingCode.js - first try**

```
define(
    ['pagarmeJs'],function (pagarme) {...})
```

**jsFileWithTheCallingCode.js - second try**

```
define(
    ['pagarmeJs'],function () {...})
```

As mentioned above, if I try to insert the **pagarme** variable on the console or use inside the require function I always get error messages.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Simply I use the code bellow in **requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        pagarme: 'https://assets.pagar.me/pagarme-js/3.0/pagarme.min'
    }
};
```

And the global variable works!